# Couldn't create application in spinnaker UI

Tags: kubernetes, devops, spinnaker-halyard, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I've used Oracle IaaS K8s environment. So, all configuration changes are done successfully, But when I'm creating the Application I've got "Could not create application: Cannot get property 'name' on null object" message.
Could you please help me to solve this issue.

I've configured persistentStorage as oraclebmcs , configure docker registry, kubernetes accounts and also enable the oraclebmcs.

persistentStorage config :

```
oraclebmcs:
      bucketName: spinnaker_oracle
      namespace: spinnaker
      compartmentId: ocid1.compartment.xxxxx
      region: us-phoenix-1
      userId: ocid1.user.xxxxx
      fingerprint: e4:14:a1:2a:xxxxxx
      sshPrivateKeyFilePath: /home/.oci/oci_api_key.pem
      tenancyId: ocid1.tenancy.xxxxxxxxx
```

oraclebmcs config :

```
oraclebmcs:
      enabled: true
      accounts:
      - name: oracle-bmcs
        requiredGroupMembership: []
        compartmentId: ocid1.compartment.xxxxxxx
        userId: ocid1.user.xxxxxxx
        fingerprint: e4:14:a1:2a:xxxxxxx
        sshPrivateKeyFilePath: /home/.oci/oci_api_key.pem
        tenancyId: ocid1.tenancy.xxxxxxx
        region: us-ashburn-1
```

k8s account :

```
kubernetes:
        enabled: true
        name: oracle-k8s-automate
        requiredGroupMembership: []
        providerVersion: V1
        dockerRegistries:
        - accountName: docker
          namespaces: []
        configureImagePullSecrets: true
        namespaces: []
        omitNamespaces: []
        kinds: []
        omitKinds: []
        customResources: []
        kubeconfigFile: /home/chalaka/cloud/configuraiton/kubeconfig_auto
        oauthScopes: []
        oAuthScopes: []
```